# @Produces collection in JAXRS / RestEasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly-9

I found some strange behaviour that I cannot understand.

I have tested 4 similar examples:

## 1

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response produce() {
    List<Book> books = Arrays
            .asList(new Book[] { 
                    new Book("aaa", "AAA", "12345"), 
                    new Book("bbb", "BBB", "09876") 
                    });
    return Response.ok(books).build();
}
```

## 2

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Book> produce() {
    List<Book> books = Arrays
            .asList(new Book[] { 
                    new Book("aaa", "AAA", "12345"), 
                    new Book("bbb", "BBB", "09876") 
                    });
    return books;
}
```

## 3

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Book> produce() {
    List<Book> books = Arrays
            .asList(new Book[] { 
                    new Book("aaa", "AAA", "12345"), 
                    new Book("bbb", "BBB", "09876") 
                    });
    return books;
}
```

## 4

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response produce() {
    List<Book> books = Arrays
            .asList(new Book[] { 
                    new Book("aaa", "AAA", "12345"), 
                    new Book("bbb", "BBB", "09876") 
                    });
    return Response.ok(books).build();
}
```

Everything works in #1, #2, #3 but 4th example throws:

> Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:
>   java.util.Arrays$ArrayList of media type: application/xml.

I run it on Wildfly 9 and I wonder if it is related to RestEasy or JaxRS in general? I know that I can fix it by wrapping collection in GenericEntity, but I don't understand this inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: It may depends on what is needed to build the final String document (JSON or XML). For XML it may be important to know the Class of the Generic attribute as it is used to build the tag. That may be why JSON goes on and not XML. By reading [this article](http://aruld.info/handling-generified-collections-in-jersey-jax-rs/) the problem is clearly that the type is lost during the treatment with Response answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the missing of type information. This is required for JAXB, which handles the XML serialization.

1 and 2 works because Jackson is being used for JSON, and it generally doesn't need to know type information as it just introspects properties.

3 works because type information is known through the method return type.

4 doesn't work because there is no type information. It's is erased by [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). That's where `GenericEntity` comes to the rescue. It stores the type information.

> [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html)
>
> Normally type erasure removes generic type information such that a `Response` instance that contains, e.g., an entity of type `List<String>` appears to contain a raw `List<?>` at runtime. When the generic type is required to select a suitable `MessageBodyWriter`, this class may be used to wrap the entity and capture its generic type.

Comment: As I understand type erasure removes all generic types, so List<Book> are converted to simply List in both cases #3 and #4. Why JAXRS (or JAXB actually) knows which MessageBodyWriter to use in #3 and it has problem with that in #4? Aren't the Response.ok() or ResponseBuilder.entity() only the additional wrappers for #3 case?

Comment: The method signature has the type in #3, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

swch, i create an example of MessageBodyWriter for Collections (Set, List etc)
Also, some can analyze Annotation for xml root name, gzip, and cache... have fun!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public class CollectionProvider
  implements MessageBodyWriter<Collection>
{
  static final byte[] COMMA = ",".getBytes();
  static final byte[] ARRAY_START = "[".getBytes();
  static final byte[] ARRAY_END = "]".getBytes();
  static final byte[] NULL = "null".getBytes();
  static final QName OBJECT = new QName(null, "object");

  @Override
  public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType)
  {
    if (!Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
      return false;

    if (genericType == null || !(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType))
      return false;

    Type[] args = ((ParameterizedType) genericType).getActualTypeArguments();

    for (Type arg: args)
    {
      if (arg instanceof TypeVariable) // can't mashal Collection<T>
        return false;

      if (!(arg instanceof Class))
        return false;
    }

    String type = mediaType.getType().toLowerCase();
    String subtype = mediaType.getSubtype().toLowerCase();

    return type.equals("application") && 
      (subtype.startsWith("json") || subtype.startsWith("xml"));
  }

  @Override
  public long getSize(Collection list, Class<?> c, Type type, Annotation[] annotation, MediaType mediaType)
  {
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeTo(Collection list, Class<?> c, Type type, Annotation[] annotation, MediaType mediaType,
                      MultivaluedMap<String, Object> multivaluedMap, OutputStream outputStream)
    throws IOException, WebApplicationException
  {
    try
    {
      boolean json = mediaType.getSubtype().toLowerCase().startsWith("json");

      if (list.isEmpty())
      {
        if(json)
        {
          outputStream.write(ARRAY_START);
          outputStream.write(ARRAY_END);
        }
        else
          outputStream.write("<list/>".getBytes());
      }
      else
      {
        Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<Class>();

        for (Type clazz: ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments())
          classes.add((Class) clazz);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]));
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, false);

        if(json)
        {
          m.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
          m.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
        }

        if(json)
          outputStream.write(ARRAY_START);
        else
          outputStream.write("<list>".getBytes());

        for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
          Object object = it.next();

          if(json)
          {
            if (object == null) // Allow nullabale value collections
              outputStream.write(NULL);
            else
              m.marshal(new JAXBElement(OBJECT, object.getClass(), object), outputStream);

            if (it.hasNext())
              outputStream.write(COMMA);
          }
          else if (object != null) // null in xml? xm...
            m.marshal(object, outputStream); // <-- requered XmlRoot annotation
        }

        if(json)
          outputStream.write(ARRAY_END);
        else
          outputStream.write("</list>".getBytes());
      }
    }
    catch (JAXBException e)
    {
      throw new IOException(e);
    }
  }
}
```